# For any basis of a dual space $B^*$, does there always exist a basis $B$ so that the dual basis of $B$ equals $B^*$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vectorspace, and $V^*$ its dual. I wonder now if for every basis $B^*$ of $V^*$, I can find a basis $B$ so that its dual basis is exactly $B^*$.

It can't find a proof for this and I hope someone can help.

Comment: Are you working in a finite-dimensional setting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the finite-dimensional setting, we have a natural isomorphism $V = V^{**}$, so that you can identify the dual basis $B^{**}$ of a dual basis $B^*$ of $V^*$ with a basis $B$ of $V$.

Comment: and in the infinite-dimensional case, I think reflexivity is precisely the needed condition; a Banach space $X$ is reflexive if $X^{**} = X$.

Comment: Thank you (I was indeed working in a finite-dimensional setting). That was easier than I thought.

Answer (score 1):

Take $\Bbb R^\infty = \left\{\left(u_n\right)_{n \in \Bbb N}\in \Bbb R ^ \Bbb N \mid \exists n_0 \in \Bbb N, \forall n \ge n_0, u_n = 0\right\}$

It's a vector subspace of $\Bbb R ^ \Bbb N$

Take $\left(e_k\right)_{k\in \Bbb N}$ is a basis of $\Bbb R^\infty$

---

$\left(R^\infty\right)^*=L\left(\Bbb R ^ \infty, \Bbb R\right)$

Take $\forall k,n \in \Bbb N, \epsilon_k(e_n)=\delta_{k,n}$

$\left(\varepsilon_k\right)_{k\in \Bbb N}$ are independant vectors of $\left(R^\infty\right)^*$ but do not form a basis

For example $f:\left(u_n\right)_{n \in \Bbb N}\mapsto \sum\limits_{k=0}^{+\infty}u_n \in L\left(\Bbb R ^ \infty, \Bbb R\right)$ can not be expressed as a **finite** linear combinaison of the $\varepsilon_k$